# Auto Frame Height for UILabel without Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, layout, frame

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the following. I need to have a custom height for the frame that changes with the amount of lines that the UILabel has.

```
let titleLabel:UILabel = 
titleLabel.text = "The Never Ending Story That Never Ends"
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping // or NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Geomanist-Medium", size: 32)
titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(16 + xOffset, screenSize.width + 20, screenSize.width - 32, 100)
self.scrollView.addSubview(titleLabel)
```

What I'm trying to do is replace the titleLabel.frame's height, with a variable that gets updated automatically based off of the number of lines in the UILabel, but preferably it's natural height. Any ideas or workarounds?

Thanks,
Liam

Comment: as far as i know, line break mode doesn't work without auto layout !!!! IF you want uilabel to increase height, you need to use auto layout!!!! Constraint its width and use line break mode!!!!

Comment: I think that you need to set the frame however like this in order to add it as a subview... Am I wrong?

Comment: Line break mode does work btw. The problem is that if there are three lines then the height changes as opposed to 1 or 2 lines. So setting the height of the frame to a constant just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the size of multiple lines of text you can use

```
func boundingRectWithSize(_ size: CGSize,
                  options options: NSStringDrawingOptions,
               attributes attributes: [String : AnyObject]?,
                  context context: NSStringDrawingContext?) -> CGRect
```

Where size is the width you want for the label and some really large number for the height. You should read the caveats in the NSString class reference.